# Finding closed form of sequence $0, 2, 10, 28, 60, 110, 182,...$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, number-systems

Need to find closed form of this sequence.

$0, 2, 10, 28, 60, 110, 182, 280, 408, 570, 770,...$

I've tried some obvious ideas but yet to have a luck.

Comment: Why do you think there is a closed form ?

Comment: CAS says:$\frac{1}{3} (n-1) \left(2 n^2-n\right)$

Comment: @TheSilverDoe because I was asked  to find a closed form of this.

Comment: Check out the online enclocepedia of integer sequences: https://oeis.org There you can search for sequences! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of first differences is
$$
2,8,18,32,50,72,\ldots
$$
which is double the sequence of squares.  Hence the $n$th term of the original sequence is twice the sum of the first $n-1$ squares, or
$$
\frac13 (n - 1)n(2n - 1).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try this approach.  I did not work it out myself, but a way to check correctness is to compare to other answers.

Given your sequence:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n= & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & ... \\ \hline
f(n)= & 0 & 2 & 10 & 28 & 60 & 110 & 182 & ...\\ \hline
\end{array}

Notice that the third differences of the sequence are constant.  So the closed form is a cubic polynomial $$ f(n) = an^3 + bn^2 + cn + d $$

So we plug in the first 4 values of $n$ to get 4 equations with 4 unknowns.  Then solve these linearly for:
$$\begin{cases} 0 = a+b+c+d \\
 2 = a(2^3) + b(2^2) + c(2)+d \\
 10 = a(3^3) + b(3^2) + c(3)+d \\
28 = a(4^3) + b(4^2) + c(4)+d \end{cases}$$